# Deleting an item from an array within an object with an HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, object, xmlhttprequest

Sorry about the word salad title, I didn't know how else to describe it.

Say I send a GET request to an API and it spits out this:

```
{
    {id: 1, name: "John Doe", tags: ["Apple", "Orange", "Pear"]},
    {id: 2, name: "Jane Doe", tags: ["Grape", "Banana", "Strawberry"]},
    {id: 3, name: "James Smith", tags:["Grapefruit", "Lemon", "Apricot"]}
}
```

If I wanted to delete the entire second object, I know I can do that with with something like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('DELETE', APIurl + "/2", true);
request.send();
```

But I'm not sure what to do if, for example, I only want to remove the "Banana" tag from the second object.
I could potentially just delete the object and then re-add it with the tag removed, but surely there's an easier way to do it?

This may be a stupid question, but I don't have much experience with APIs, and I couldn't figure it out by just googling it.

Comment: I think you're looking for a PUT request.

Comment: Is this an existing API, or are you designing one?

Comment: @BrandonD.McKay It's an existing API that I can't edit

Comment: Is there any documentation or code for the API that you can access?

Comment: @BrandonD.McKay Unfortunately not, and the guy who built it is on holiday in Ibiza, so I can't ask him :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you have to use PUT method request to do it, this might get some kind of idea to do it

```
var data = {};
data.tags = ["Grape", "Strawberry"];
var data_json = JSON.stringify(data);

request.open("PUT", APIurl+'/2', true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
request.onload = function () {
    var result = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == "200") {
       console.table(result);
   } else {
       console.error(result);
   }
}
request.send(data_json);
```